# simple C graphic library for demo a matrix

Tags: c, graphics, matrix

I have been asked to display a pretty big matrix like 200*300. It's kind ugly when i output this to console..

The matrix is changing during an iteration, I have to show this as well.
I wonder if there is a simple tool I can use to display this matrix?
hopefully, I can call it in my C program.

I don't have any graphic programming experience.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just view it in a text editor?

Comment: What is the OS you are using?

Are there any requirements? (ie: open-source vs commercial)

If you have MATLAB installed, you can just dump the matrix to a CSV text file and then import and display it with two lines of code in MATLAB.

Comment: @Pubby the problem is the matrix is supposed to be update during an iteration..I have to demo this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try GNUPlot:

OSX Installation:
http://www.miscdebris.net/blog/2009/09/16/install-gnuplot-on-mac-os-x/

Project Homepage:
http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html

I have used it in numerous projects. It is very easy to generate plots. In your case, you could just create a scatter plot, and export it to JPEG in a few simple steps.

If you don't want to have to build and integrate it into your application, you can just send commands via the "system" function to a prebuilt GNUPlot application.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/

Answer (score 0):

You could use SDL (libsdl.org) to make a display window and output each character as a pixel on the window.

Here is a test app so you can take a look at how it works:
http://friedspace.com/SDLTest.c

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you want to go into a graphics library for this.  Instead, I would suggest dumping the data to an output file, and handling it from there.

For one, you could just format it to fixed-width fields, and view the text file with a text editor:

```
000  001  002
099  098  097
...
```

Or, you could consider dumping it as [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), and importing it into something like Excel.